# Rearrange items in ListBox

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, listbox

I have a ListBox with a number of ListBoxItem objects. What is the best way to allow users to rearrange the items by dragging and dropping? Do I have to use StackPanels instead?
Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to use a different listbox control or build your own. [Here](http://www.xdevsoftware.com/blog/post/Reorderlist-with-Silverlight-3-Drag-and-Drop-Listbox-.aspx) is an example of building your own. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SL4DragDropListBox.aspx) is another one where he extends the silverlight toolkit listbox control.

Answer (score 0):

For prosperity, the Silverlight Toolkit offers a set of `DragDropTarget's` which can be used to reorder items within a `ListBox`, `TreeView`, or a simple `ItemsControl`.  You can also drag items between `ItemsControls`.  Run the Silverligh 4 samples project and look at 'Drag and Drop' under the Toolkit section.

http://silverlight.codeplex.com/

http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl4/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html

The controls you want are:

```
ListBoxDragDropTarget
TreeViewDragDropTarget
DataPointSeriesDragDropTarget
```